# An equality about integration

Tags: calculus

Suppose $f(x)\in c(-\infty, +\infty), f(x)\geq 0,$ and 
$f(x)\int^x_0 f(t)dt = sin^4x$,  then
 $$\int^\pi_0 f(t)dt=\frac{\sqrt{3\pi}}{2}$$

How to prove it?  I would appreciate it if someone can give any suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If
$$ g(x)= \int_{0}^x f(t) dt \implies g'(x)=f(x), g(0)=0~~~(1)$$
So we have$$2 g'(x) g(x)=2\sin^4 x, \forall x \in R \implies (g^2(x))' =2\sin^4 x $$ $$\implies g^2(x)=\int 2 \sin^4 x dx=\frac{3x}{4}-\frac{1}{2}\sin 2x+ \frac{1}{16} \sin 4x+C$$
as $g(0)=0 \implies C=0$
So $$g^2(\pi)=\frac{3 \pi}{4} \implies \int_{0}^{\pi} f(t) dt=\frac{\sqrt{3\pi}}{2}$$ from (1).

Comment: Good work ! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Let F(x) = integral from 0 to x of f(t) st.

Then, f(x)=F'(x)

So you have a differential equation F' * F = sin^4(x)

Solve for F and plug in pi.